# Ableton Link in a VST Plugin possible?

Tags: audio, plugins, synchronization, vst

First i am not really a coder more a musician.

[Ableton Link](https://www.ableton.com/en/link/) comes more and more to our devices in apps but not in DAWs like Cubase, Bitwig, Logic, FL Studio, Cakewalk, etc.

So is it possible to grab the song tempo from a DAW and transmit it via the Ableton Link protocol over a VST plugin? Ok, mostly it is an one way synchronization. A VST plugin can't set the host tempo. But hey, for me its ok when my devices (iOS, Android apps with Ableton Link support) are in sync!

Hope it is clear what i mean and hoping here for a magic VST coder to realize my dream!

More Ableton Link on [GitHub...](https://ableton.github.io/link/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is theoretically possible. There is nothing special about the Link framework to prevent it from being used in a VST. But as you noted, the host will be unable to accept tempo changes from the plugin. Maybe this is a limitation which is acceptable in certain use-cases.

Rather than pleading for a random magic VST coder to realize your dream, perhaps you should encourage the creators of your DAW of choice to integrate Link in their application. ;)

Comment: I think the devs of the DAWs have other prioritizes then Ableton Link except Ableton. Maybe next year. A magic VST coder needs, mmh, 1-2 weeks for a first version?! I am willing to donate something ;)